# Beginner help on arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Hello and firstly thanks for checking out my post today! I'm fairly new to developing as a whole but over the past few weeks have been taking various online courses and reading into javascript and nodejs.

The following array is an important piece in my current project,

```
let row = [button_one, button_two, button_three, button_delete];
```

and each variable has it's own place in my json configuration files, which looks as follows,

```
{
    "Button_One": true,
    "Button_Two": false,
    "Button_Three": false
}
```

My plan was to only have the corresponding buttons set to true in the json file *appear* in the array. I'm sure this is possible however it's not a technique I have come across yet, so hopefully somebody can help me.

Let me apologise if my question is painfully simple, or stupid. As I mentioned I'm new the developing and it's all a little intimidating at the moment, thanks for the help in advance!

I haven't logically thought of a solution to my problem yet. Therefore I have had no attempts to solve my problem!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the array does? And why are the buttons managed in two places?

Comment: In this instance the array collects all the variables to build a component, (a separate function) and the json file is there for user accessibility. I can't quite figure out a method to ensure only the buttons enabled in the json file are used in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const object = {
"Button_One": true,
"Button_Two": false,
"Button_Three": false
};

let arr = [];

for (const el in object) {
  if (object[el] === true) {
    arr.push(el)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using the [for in loop ][1] to filter the object and then push it into the array.


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thanks this works for the most part however it's not applicable for my project yet as the variables are in a string, the button values store data. If that makes sense? The output is
`[ 'button_one', 'button_two' ]` and it would need to be `[ button_one, button_two ]`

Comment: Instead of an array of string values, it'd be better to manage this data in an array of objects. That way you can have multiple data properties that give you more context on the data, rather than simply relying on its position in an array to identify it.